# DeleteObject Method doesn't come

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1, entity

This is my code to delete a link. When i try to db.deleteobject.. deleteobject method is not shown in there. What should i do.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LinkDelete(int id)
        { 
            AralContainer db = new AralContainer("VefatilaniCS");
            Link lnk = db.Links.Where(x => x.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
            db.Links.DeleteObject(lnk);  // This is the line i got error 
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: What is AralContainer? Did you include reference to System.Data.Entity? I wouldn't recommend you to mix the code working with database and web in one place.

Comment: AralContainer is my DataContext, and i added system.data.entity in the references. I didn't understand why its not coming.. Here is the full error.

Comment: Error 2 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Aralreklam.Vefatilani.Entity.Link>' does not contain a definition for 'deleteobject' and no extension method 'deleteobject' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Aralreklam.Vefatilani.Entity.Link>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Murat\Desktop\Aralreklam.Vefatilani - Copy - Copy - Copy\Aralreklam.Vefatilani.UI.Web\Areas\Admin\Controllers\HomeController.cs 184 22 Aralreklam.Vefatilani.UI.Web

Comment: The method is `Remove()` but I guess you found out in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
Link lnk = db.Links.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id)
```

Where().Single() is actually returning you DbSet which is not what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to add reference to some assemblies. Check if your web app has the following references:

```
System.Data.Entity (using System.Data.Entity)
using System.Linq
```

And, by the way System.Data.Entity doesn't have any DeleteObject, only Remove()